# Criar temas no app Android

Tags: android, sqlite, actionbar

Gente, é possível customizar a cor do action bar no Android, pois estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e eu queria que os usuários pudessem escolher a cor da aplicação que mais gostar. Alguém sabe se é possível fazer isso com o appcompat.

Comment: É possível sim, e existem várias formas de fazer isso. Legal seria fazer um gridview com várias cores. Desta forma, na medida que o usuário escolher uma cor, o tema muda de acordo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você utilizar uma `Toolbar`, sim. ela está na biblioteca `appcompat-v7` e você deve escolher o tema NoActionBar para o app:

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

Insira uma Toolbar no seu layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">
</LinearLayout>
```

Agora no Activity identifique a Toolbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Lembrando que o Activity deve ser do tipo `AppCompatActivity` ou `ActionBarActivity`:

```
public class MeuActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

Agora a sua Toolbar é uma View como outra qualquer. Você pode alterar a cor de background utilizando:

```
int corVerde = Color.parseColor("#50a600");
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(corVerde);
```

Comment: Consegui, valeu pela sugestão, em breve vou postar no github a solução.